# How to add an embedded image to an HTML message in Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook, cdo.message, outlook-object-model

I have Office 2003 VBA code that uses [the technique described here](http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/htmlimg.htm) to embed an image in an HTML message using undocumented MAPI properties and CDO 1.21.

CDO 1.21 is no longer supported, but [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692174.aspx#OfficeOutlook2010PlatformBitnessSupport), most of its functionality is now incorporated into the Outlook 2010 object model.

Where can I find a sample that embeds images in an Outlook 2010 message using the Outlook 2010 object model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7446).

The key bits being:

```
Const PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001E"        
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"        
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B" 

...

Set colAttach = l_Msg.Attachments        
For x = 1 To Items.Count            
    Set l_Attach = colAttach.Add(Items.Item(x))            
    Set oPA = l_Attach.PropertyAccessor            
    oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG, ItemTypes.Item(x)            
    oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "item" & x            
    oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN, True        
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Here other example:

```
Option Explicit
'Add reference to MS Outlook x.x Object Library
'Picture to be added as an attachment and modified src location for each embedded picture.
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmail As MailItem
    Dim colAttach As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment

    'create new Outlook MailItem
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    'add graphic as attachment to Outlook message
    'change path to graphic as needed
    Set colAttach = oEmail.Attachments
    Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("D:\my documents\[color=red]MyPic.jpg[/color]")
    oEmail.Close olSave
    'change the src property to 'cid:your picture filename'
    'it will be changed to the correct cid when its sent.
    oEmail.HTMLBody = "<BODY><FONT face=Arial color=#000080 size=2></FONT>" & _
    "<IMG alt='' hspace=0 src='[color=red]cid:MyPic.jpg[/color]' align=baseline border=0>&nbsp;</BODY>"
    oEmail.Save
    oEmail.Display 'fill in the To, Subject, and Send. Or program it in.
    Set oEmail = Nothing
    Set colAttach = Nothing
    Set oAttach = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

you can find it on:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?278600-VB-Embedd-an-image-into-an-Outlook-email-message-body

Answer (score 1):

This is a vb code snippet by Dmitry Streblechenko (MVP). It worked fine for me.

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Ns = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Ns.Logon
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set objOutlookRecip = objOutlookMsg.Recipients.Add("test@dimastr.com")
objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo
objOutlookMsg.Subject = "test"
' add graphic as attachment to Outlook message
Set colAttach = objOutlookMsg.Attachments
Set l_Attach = colAttach.Add("z:\Temp\8\1.jpg ")
l_Attach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F", "image/jpeg"  '
Change From 0x370eE001E
l_Attach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "myident"
'Changed from 0x3712001E
objOutlookMsg.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B", True
'
Set body format to HTML
objOutlookMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = "html tags goes here< img align="
baseline " order="
1 " hspace="
0 " src="
cid: myident " width="
" 600="
" > </img> end html tags"
objOutlookMsg.Save
objOutlookMsg.Send
```

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work any more, "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." anyway I can get the lastest one?

Comment: There are not links but DASL property names of the MAPI properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I've found works the best for me.  I used to just link to the subfolder but found some international users experienced huge lag and even crashed there inbox.  I switched to the below so that the image was imbedded in the email and it solved the lag issues because the file is actually embedded in the email.

```
Sub sendKeyMailer()


Dim emlMsg As Object
    Set emlMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    strBody = "<html> yadda yadda tricks are for kids. <br><br>"
    strBody = strBody & "<img src=""cid:myimage.jpg""><BR><BR>"
    strBody = strBody & "but tricks make the world go round.</html>"

    emlMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    emlMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "<<yourserver>>"
    emlMsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    emlMsg.Configuration.Fields.Update
    
    emlMsg.AddRelatedBodyPart "C:\temp\The Big Eskimo Roll.jpg", "myimage.jpg", cdoRefTypeId
    emlMsg.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<myimage.jpg>"
    emlMsg.Fields.Update
        
    
    With emlMsg
            .To = "allthepeople@yourcompany.com"
            .From = "aGrpLst@yourcompany.com"
            .Subject = "Humpty dumpty had a great fall"  '''I have kids....;^D.....
            .HTMLbody = strBody
            '.AddAttachment "C:\temp\The Big Eskimo Roll.jpg"
            .Send
    End With

    Set emlMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```