# Add image from Excel sheet to Outlook HTML body using Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to add an image from an Excel sheet to an Outlook email.

I tried using a link to an image stored in a network location and on the Internet. However, not all users will have access to these locations.

Is it possible to store the image in another worksheet and then copy it into the email body?

I know the below won't work because you can't export shapes but can I do something like this?

```
ActiveUser = Environ$("UserName")
TempFilePath = "C:\Users\" & ActiveUser & "\Desktop\"

Sheets("Images").Shapes("PanelComparison").Export TempFilePath & "\PanelComparison.png"
panelimage = "<img src = ""TempFilePath\PanelComparison.png"" width=1000 height=720 border=0>"
```

Answer (score 1):

The CreateEmail Sub calls the SaveToImage Sub. The SaveToImage sub grabs a range, creates a chart on a new page and then saves the picture(objChart) to a specified directory.

The LMpic string variable calls the image just saved and inputs it into the HTML body.

```
Public Sub CreateEmail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim FN, LN, EmBody, EmBody1, EmBody2, EmBody3 As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Call SaveToImage


ws.Activate

LMpic = wb.Path & "\ClarityEmailPic.jpg'"

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

        FN = Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
        LN = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value
        EmBody = Range("Email_Body").Value
        EmBody1 = Range("Email_Body1").Value
        EmBody2 = Range("Email_Body2").Value
        'EmBody3 = Range("Email_Body3").Value

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Volt Clarity Reminder "
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
            .HTMLBody = "<html><br><br><br>" & _
                            "<table border width=300 align=center>" & _
                                "<tr bgcolor=#FFFFFF>" & _
                                    "<td align=right>" & _
                                        "<img src='" & objRange & "'>" & _
                                    "</td>" & _
                                "</tr>" & _
                                "<tr border=0.5 height=7 bgcolor=#102561><td colspan=2></td></tr>" & _
                                "<tr>" & _
                                    "<td colspan=2 bgcolor=#E6E6E6>" & _
                                    "<body style=font-family:Arial style=backgroung-color:#FFFFFF align=center>" & _
                                            "<p> Dear " & FN & " " & LN & "," & "</p>" & _
                                            "<p>" & EmBody & "</p>" & _
                                            "<p>" & EmBody2 & "<i><font color=red>" & EmBody1 & "</i></font>" & "</p>" & _
                                    "</body></td></tr></table></html>"
            .Display  'Or use Display
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing

    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub SaveToImage()
'
' SaveToImage Macro
'

    Dim DataObj As Shape
    Dim objChart As Chart
    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim picname As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    folderpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator 'locating & assigning current folder path
    picname = "ClarityEmailPic.jpg" 'image file name

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call ws.Range("Picture").CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture) 'copying the range as an image

    Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Sheet4" 'creating a new sheet to insert the chart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    Set objChart = ActiveChart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Width = ws.Range("Picture").Width 'making chart size match image range size
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Height = ws.Range("Picture").Height

    objChart.Paste 'pasting the range to the chart
    objChart.Export (folderpath & picname) 'creating an image file with the activechart

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete 'deleting sheet4
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In general email images are stored **on a web server**, with the SRC pointing to that server (`http://...`). They're not embedded in the email itself.

Comment: Ok thanks for that but it doesn't really answer how I can put an image in excel into an email.

Comment: You may be able to do it as an attachment. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224766/how-to-add-an-embedded-image-to-an-html-message-in-outlook-2010

Comment: I could attach them but ideally I want them within the email body