# Outlook 2010 email to Web page, including images

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, outlook

I can paste an Outlook email message into a Web page using the following code.

**VBA**

```
Sub HTMLClipboard()
  Dim M As MailItem, Buf As MSForms.DataObject
  Set M = ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1)
  Set Buf = New MSForms.DataObject
  Buf.SetText M.HTMLBody
  Buf.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Data"></div>
<textarea id="TA"></textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('paste', function(e) {
  $('#TA').focus();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#Data')
      .html($('#TA').val());
  });
});
```

This works great *unless* there's an image in the HTMLBody.  In that situation, I get a broken image src like this:

```
<img width=596 height=381
 id="Picture_x0020_1" 
 src="cid:image001.png@01D07855.C2524830"
>
```

Is there a way to encode image data within the VBA function, preferably as a Data URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution, and thanks to Eugene for pointing me towards the Attachments collection.  (I didn't know it included embedded images.)

```
Sub HTMLClipboard()
  Dim M As MailItem, Buf As MSForms.DataObject
  Set M = ActiveExplorer().Selection.Item(1)
  Set Buf = New MSForms.DataObject

  b = M.HTMLBody

  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 1 To M.Attachments.Count
    fn = M.Attachments.Item(i).PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E")
    If fn > "" Then
      M.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "d:\temp"
      base64 = EncodeFile("d:\temp")
      b = Replace(b, "cid:" & fn, "data:image/png;base64," & base64)
    End If
  Next
  Buf.SetText b
  Buf.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

This code:

1. Iterates through the Attachments collection looking for embedded images.
2. Saves the image to a temporary file.
3. Converts the image binary data to base64 using the `EncodeFile` function found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134022/3903374
4. Replaces each image's `src` attribute with the base64 encoding, which turns it into a Data URI.

I'd be interested in a method that avoids creating a temporary file.

I can now run the macro in Outlook and paste onto my Web page, with image data being embedded in the HTML itself.

Answer (score 1):

> src="cid:image001.png@01D07855.C2524830"

Such source string indicates a hidden attachment with the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID (DASL name - "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E") property set to the image001.png@01D07855.C2524830 value. You can find the image using the [Attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866435(v=office.15).aspx) property of Outlook items.

See [How to add an embedded image to an HTML message in Outlook 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224766/how-to-add-an-embedded-image-to-an-html-message-in-outlook-2010) for more information.

Comment: Learning that embedded image data is in the Attachments collection is a big help, thanks.  I wonder if I could open the file, convert it to a Data URI, and replace the src attribute with that Data URI?

Comment: You can save it on the disk and then upload it on any web server.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping to embed the image within the HTML instead of as a separate file.  Once on the Web page, it will be saved to a database.

Comment: If you can save the image to disk, you can base-64 encode it, and use it in a data URI as the source for an `<img>`  https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: I think Rick knows what to do after saving the attachment.