# outlook attachment preview using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a private special email set up for only receiving scanned files.  I already have a Macro to download all attachments from a specific folder. However, I need to preview the attachments before downloading.  Is there a way to create a macro to automatically preview the attachment(s) in an email when I select the email, as opposed to selecting each attachment to preview them?

Comment: What type of file?

Comment: It is a .pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You can create / modify the HTML body to reference the images added as graphics attachments to your email.

Comment: Im not sure how to implement that. ill keep it in mind.

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224766/how-to-add-an-embedded-image-to-an-html-message-in-outlook-2010

Comment: Thank you, but that seems over complicated for what I am trying to accomplish