# Reply with .oft template and show images and attachments

Tags: vba, outlook, reply

When I create an email from an .oft template it doesn't show all the content of the e-mail.
It's missing content like images and/or attachments.

I tried to merge Sub reply1() and Sub reply2():

```
Sub Reply1()

Dim Original As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Reply As Outlook.MailItem
Set Original = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Reply
Set Reply = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Outlook\Mail.oft")

Original.HTMLBody = Reply.HTMLBody & Original.HTMLBody
Original.Display
End Sub
```

**Sub Reply1()**
This code doesn't show images or attachments of my own .oft mail.
It does show my e-mail signature but at the very bottom of both mails.
It does show the content of the e-mail I respond to correctly.

```
Sub Reply2()

Dim origEmail As MailItem
Dim replyEmail As MailItem

Set origEmail = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
Set replyEmail = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Outlook\Mail.oft")

replyEmail.To = origEmail.Reply.To

replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
replyEmail.Recipients.ResolveAll
replyEmail.Display

Set origEmail = Nothing
Set replyEmail = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Sub Reply2()** does the opposite of **Sub Reply1**.
It shows the images and attachments of my own .oft mail.
It will not show my e-mail signature correctly.
It will not display the content of the mail I respond to correctly. The images are missing

**Sub Reply1() Results:**
[image]

**Sub Reply2() Results**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below does work in my situation.

```
Sub Reply1()
Dim fromTemplate As MailItem
Dim reply As MailItem
Dim oItem As Object

Set fromTemplate = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Outlook\Mail.oft")

Set oItem = GetCurrentItem()
If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
Set reply = oItem.ReplyAll
CopyAttachments oItem, fromTemplate, reply
    
reply.HTMLBody = fromTemplate.HTMLBody & reply.HTMLBody
    
reply.Display
oItem.UnRead = False
End If
 
Set reply = Nothing
Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub


Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
     
Set objApp = Application
On Error Resume Next
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
Case "Explorer"
Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Case "Inspector"
Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Select
 
Set objApp = Nothing
End Function

Sub CopyAttachments(source1, source2, objTargetItem)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldTemp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) ' TemporaryFolder
strPath = fldTemp.Path & "\"
For Each objAtt In source1.Attachments
strFile = strPath & objAtt.fileName
objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
objTargetItem.Attachments.Add strFile, , , objAtt.DisplayName
fso.DeleteFile strFile
Next

For Each objAtt In source2.Attachments
strFile = strPath & objAtt.fileName
objAtt.SaveAsFile strFile
objTargetItem.Attachments.Add strFile, , , objAtt.DisplayName
fso.DeleteFile strFile
Next

Set fldTemp = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Embedded images are stored as hidden attachments on the email message. If you create a new Outlook item based on the template you need to re-attach the required images to get the message body rendered correctly. You can read more about that in the [How to add an embedded image to an HTML message in Outlook 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224766/how-to-add-an-embedded-image-to-an-html-message-in-outlook-2010) thread.

Also, I have noticed the following code:

```
replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
```

Remember, the HTML string should be a well-formed markup. If you want to insert something into the message body of an existing item you need to paste that inside the opening `<body>` and closing `</body>` elements. Otherwise, you may end up with a broken or improperly rendered message body. Even if Outlook do its great job by sorting most mistakes out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
It was not exactly what i was looking for but i appreciate your interest

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding an email retains attachments.

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Sub Reply_Retain_Attachments()

    Dim fromTemplate As MailItem
    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim forwardEmail As MailItem
    
    Set fromTemplate = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Outlook\Mail.oft")
    
    Set origEmail = GetCurrentItem()
    
    If Not origEmail Is Nothing Then
    
        ' Forward retains attachments
        Set forwardEmail = origEmail.Forward
        
        forwardEmail.HTMLBody = fromTemplate.HTMLBody & forwardEmail.HTMLBody
        
        forwardEmail.To = origEmail.reply.To ' keep .reply here
        
        forwardEmail.Recipients.ResolveAll
        forwardEmail.Display
        
    Else
        ' This may never occur
        MsgBox "GetCurrentItem is nothing?"
        
    End If

End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
     
    'On Error Resume Next ' uncomment if you find it necessary
    
    Select Case TypeName(ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
        Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
    Case "Inspector"
        Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Niton your code is much cleaner than my attempt.
It will not add every image as an attachment that's perfect!

But there is one thing missing when I tested your code. 
If the "Mail.oft" contains an attachments like for example a ReadMe.pdf file shown in the image "Sub Reply2()" It will not be in the reply mail. 

This is only the case for the .oft file not for the e-mail you reply to.
Those attachments will be added to your E-mail.