# Images not appearing in Outlook account of email sent with ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, email, outlook, html-email

I am trying to send mail in my ASP.NET Core MVC project. The mail is being sent successfully. But in my "Outlook" account, the picture I added to the image of the mail does not appear. When I send the same mail to my gmail account, the picture appears in the mail.

My markup:

```
<img src="example.png" width="100%">
```

I replace the src field in the code.

The view code generated in the mail is:

```
<img data-imagetype="External" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBTAA7" originalsrc="example.png" data-imageproxyendpoint="/actions/ei" width="100%">
```

Instead of the picture I gave in the src field, it says something ridiculous. What is the reason of this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224766/how-to-add-an-embedded-image-to-an-html-message-in-outlook-2010

Answer (score 0):

`Base64` images are not supported by Outlook. You need to attach an image and use the `cid` attribute in the HTML markup of your message body:

```
<img src="cid:myImage.png"/>
```

Where the `myImage.png` is the filename of the attached file.

Comment: This is not working. This problem still persists. I'm attaching it with a link I got from the official website. Could the problem be related to this? I've tried every method I've seen on the internet but it doesn't work.

Comment: Again, base64 images are not supported by Outlook. Could you be more specific? What link you are attaching?